# AngularJS Cannot show authentication status

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, authentication

I am very new to AngularJS so apologies first!

I have an Angular app uses a REST API on the back-end to log users in/out

However I am trying to show the user's logged in status on the Angular front-end but not having much success.

My users are logged in and out using "authService.js":

```
app.factory('authService', ['$http', '$q', 'localStorageService', function ($http, $q, localStorageService) {

    // dec the home of the API
    var serviceBase = '<domain>' // remember to change this to the current domain that the API is being hosted!
    var authServiceFactory = {};

    // Local Authentication Data
    var _authentication = {
        isAuth: false,
        userName: ""
    };

    // Attempt to log in the user here
    var _login = function (loginData) {
        // This will be the body data of the login requesst
        var data = "grant_type=password&username=" + loginData.userName + "&password=" + loginData.password;
        var deferred = $q.defer(); // This gets the async data (AngularJS Call)

        // Send a post request to the /token endpoint to request a login
        $http.post(serviceBase + 'token', data, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } }).success(
            function (response) {
                // If the response was a 200 Success, then the user can be logged in locally
                // Store the auth token
                localStorageService.set('authorizationData', { token: response.access_token, userName: loginData.userName });
                // set local client data
                _authentication.isAuth = true;
                _authentication.userName = loginData.userName;
                // Return the promise
                deferred.resolve(response);
            }).error(function (err, status) {
                // Response from the HTTP was bad, i.e. not 200
                // flush the user and reject thee promise
                _logOut();
                deferred.reject(err);
            });
        return deferred.promise; // return the promise
    };

    // Remove the token from local storage
    var _logOut = function () {
        localStorageService.remove('authorizationData');
        _authentication.isAuth = false;
        _authentication.userName = "";
    };

    // This is run at start. Tries to get the autherizationData and if it is there then
    // the user is considered logged in
    var _fillAuthData = function () {
        var authData = localStorageService.get('authorizationData');
        if (authData) {
            _authentication.isAuth = true;
            _authentication.userName = authData.userName;
        }
    }

    // Assign all the attributs of the service facotry
    authServiceFactory.saveRegistration = _saveRegistration;
    authServiceFactory.login = _login;
    authServiceFactory.logOut = _logOut;
    authServiceFactory.fillAuthData = _fillAuthData;
    authServiceFactory.authentication = _authentication;

    console.log("Auth at end of factory:");
    console.log(_authentication.isAuth);

    // Return this object
    return authServiceFactory;
}]);
```

So, this factory should produce an object `authServiceFactory`. The `authServiceFactory.authentication` object is the data I require to present to the user, specifically `.isAuth`. From here I would be able to hide links, show the username to the user etc...

In my main App.js file I have:

```
var app = angular.module('AngularAuthApp', ['ngRoute', 'LocalStorageModule', 'angular-loading-bar']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {

    // Declaire routes...
    $routeProvider.when("/home", {
        controller: "homeController",
        templateUrl: "/app/views/home.html"
    });

    $routeProvider.when("/login", {
        controller: "loginController",
        templateUrl: "/app/views/login.html"
    });

    $routeProvider.when("/signup", {
        controller: "signupController",
        templateUrl: "/app/views/signup.html"
    });

    // redirect the user if they try to access anything else
    $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: "/home" });
});

// On the app running run the authService to get auth data
app.run(['authService', function (authService) {
    authService.fillAuthData();
}]);

// Set the application config
// Any http request push it though the authInterceptorService
app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptorService');
});
```

Notice `app.run` will collect the current authentication data from the factory.

And in my main single-paged HTML document I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="AngularAuthApp">
<head>
    <meta content="IE=edge, chrome=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" />
    <link href="content/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="content/css/loading-bar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="content/css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js" integrity="sha256-a23g1Nt4dtEYOj7bR+vTu7+T8VP13humZFBJNIYoEJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
            <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                <li ng-hide="!authentication.isAuth"><a href="#/chargers">Welcome {{authentication.userName}}</a></li>
                <li ng-hide="!authentication.isAuth"><a href="" data-ng-click="logOut()">Logout</a></li>
                <li ng-hide="authentication.isAuth"><a href="#/login"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Login</a></li>
                <li ng-hide="authentication.isAuth"><a href="#/signup"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div> ...
```

My users can log in with no problem! and the status is changing which I found using the chrome debugger. However the I cannot reflect the results through the HTML. The list items are NOT being shown when a user loggs in. Adding {{authentication.isAuth}} to my html page shows nothing.

How can I hide/show the links, and represent visually that the user is currently logged in?

Answer (score 0):

Have a $rootScope variable flag in your AuthFactory and update it after the successful login.

```
$rootScope.isAuthenticated = false; // Not authenticated
function login(){
    $http.post('RESTcalls').then(function(data){
        $rootScope.isAuthenticated = true; // Authenticated
    })
}
```

Comment: I get $rootScope is undefined so this method isn't working unfortunatly

Comment: If it is undefined you have to define it in your script.

Comment: Inject $rootScope in your controller / factory before you use it.

Comment: I have put `app.factory('authService', ['$rootScope', '$http', '$q', 'localStorageService', function ($rootScope, $http, $q, localStorageService)` in my auth Service, but I get a strange error now: `Error: [ng:areq]`

Comment: Make sure that you are not redefining the angular module of same name.